# Sending log from filebeat to logstash error: Failed to publish events caused by: lumberjack protocol error

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat, elk

Halo guys
I'm new with ELK Stack
I try to send IIS log from FileBeat to Logstash and further but it doesn't work.
I get an error *Failed to publish events caused by: lumberjack protocol error* when start FileBeat (Logstash is running)

Here all my config

*filebeat.yml*

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - e:\\elk\\iislog\\*
  exclude_lines: ['#']
filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

*logstash.yml*

```
 node.name: main
 pipeline.id: main
 pipeline.workers: 2
 http.host: "localhost"
 http.port: 5044
```

*logstash.iis.conf*

```
input {  
   beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
}

output {

}
```

*iis.yml*

```
- module: iis
  # Access logs
  access:
    enabled: true
    var.paths: 
        - e:\elk\iislog\*.log
  error:
    enabled: true
```

Logstash screen stand at line *Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>5044}* 
All stack are version 7.4.0

Can you guys show me what am i doing wrong
Thanks

Comment: You are trying to use the same port for logstash and for the beats input, it won't work. Remove the config `http.port` from your `logstash.yml` file and restart logstash.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest, I removed the config as you said and now it throw new error : dial tcp [::1]:5044: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Can you help me ?

Comment: It's working now, my bad to use one file and edit other file